# Background application listen for shortcut keys?

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, hook

I need to listen to few keys in my "background" application.
My application runs in background and is used to emulate keyboard input based on what user pressed on keyboard. It sounds strange but it actually is a very handy application. For example when I type "address" followed by double space bar it replaces it with my full address. I defined more "macros" like that. I wanted to share my application with friends.

But there is a problem with AV software telling them that this application is suspicious.
This is not a great problem, as my friends can mark that application as "trusted", but it takes time and very frustrating.

I tried hooking keyboard input. I used SetWindowsHookEx with keyboard hook. But there is a small problem. Nearly all the virus protection programs detect it as some kind of harmful program.

**What is the proper / AV friendly way of making such program?**

P.S.
I'm using C++ with WinApi.

Comment: Sorry dude, we can't help you here. Different AV use different virus detection algorithms and you probably can't avoid all of them; that's the whole point of their existence.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy That is why I'm asking. How other programs (music players, keyboard macro softwere, teamspeak with "Push to talk" method) are working fine with AV?

Answer (score 0):

If you indicate in your program manifest that it needs to run with elevated privileges, the AV programs shouldn't bother you any more.  That is not the preferred way to write an app, but sometimes it is necessary for low-level stuff like you are trying to do.

Here is a link that gives you the details on how to implement requesting elevated privileges:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact you should consider three different things :
1. The behavior of an AV program is not always deterministic to you, because they change their rules as needed. 
2. Different AV programs use different rules. 
3. Back when I wrote a kiosk program which needed to block certain key combinations, I marked my app to run with elevated privileges, as @edtheprogrammerguy suggested and it worked fine with norton, kaspersky and bitdefender . Hope it helps